# Why does this not work in IE8?

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I've got to compare my website in both Firefox and IE8. There is one difference that I just can't understand why it's doing it.

I believe that the problem is because of this line of code

```
 ul.dropdown > li:last-child {width: 50px;}
```

Does anyone know why this may not be working? Does IE8 not like angle brackets/ :last-child in CSS

Comment: IE and Firefox are a little poopy with CSS in the first place, last-child is only supported in above IE9.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you out: http://css-plus.com/2011/03/prevent-last-child-from-slowing-you-down/

Answer (score 3):

[:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child) is only supported in IE >=9

Comment: +1 from me. this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The *last-child* selector is not available in IE8 and earlier versions.

You can, however, support these early browsers with a little jQuery magic:

```
$("ul.dropdown li:last-child").addClass("last-child");
```

and then in css you can do this:

```
ul.dropdown li.last-child,
ul.dropdown li:last-child {
    /* Your CSS styling here */
}
```

Just know that the styling will only apply after jQuery gets a chance to apply the class to the last child. It is good practice to use this technique with the original selector.

For more info on the *last-child* selector, you can visit this useful page:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know children aren't supported in IE8 and below.  COULD be wrong.

Easy fix would just be

```
<li class="last">List Item</li>

.last {width: 50px;}
```